# How to find number of disctinct functions from set A to set B

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let's say there is set A {1, 2, 3} and set B {a, b}
While, I know that to find the total number of functions, it's just
number of elements from B ^ number of elements from A
But I just don't understand why?
If every elements from A maps to B, you get (1, a) (1, b) (2, a) (2, b) (3, a) (3, b)
I just can't get my head around, why is it 8 distinct functions and not 6 in this example

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way.  If $A$ has three elements and $B$ has two, then a function from $A$ to $B$ is determined by where it sends the three elements of $A$.  However, for each of the three elements of $A$, there are two choices of where to send it in $B$.  Hence, there are 8 possible functions.  Do you see how I got that?

Now, what if $A$ has $m$ elements and $B$ has $n$?